# How to test a code online?

Tags: c, interview, coding, google

I am preparing for technical interview and would like to brush my coding skills.
I have written a C++ program and would like to test it online. I don't have access to any linux compiler on my machine. Where can I do it? I have perception that I can do it in code.google.com -> Google Code Playground

but I don't see where I can choose my compiler.

I have written a simple C hello world program in "edit code" panel and have clicked on "Run code" but it has been a while and nothing appears in bottom output window.

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Ideone](http://ideone.com/). I use it all the time when I need to try something out but doesn't have the necessary compiler/interpreter running on my machine. Besides, you can also share your code, which is useful for websites like this one.

Comment: I only wish they integrated Clang, gcc is good for code generation, but the diagnostic messages *uh*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a Linux machine to access a c++ compiler?  On a Windows machine you can install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) -- the GNU `gcc/g++` compilers for Windows.  If you need more of a complete Unix environment as well (grep, sed, awk, the works...) you can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - a GNU environment for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answers, there are many prebuilt virtual machines that you can use to run an instance of linux.  These can be used for a large amount of development against machines you don't have access to.